# SQLTaskMetrics and memory consumption

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark task crashes with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded". jmap -histo gives:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:     112049437     3585581984  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ui.SQLTaskMetrics
   2:     119124871     2858996904  java.lang.Long
   3:     118862070     2852689680  scala.collection.mutable.DefaultEntry
   4:       6791309     1185711120  [Lscala.collection.mutable.HashEntry;
```

SQLTaskMetrics is related to Spark metrics to my knowledge. Is it possible to disable metrics or at least reduce the SQLTaskMetrics memory footprint as much as possible?

**The problem was solved** by cloning and building the last version of Spark 1.5.1:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/apache/spark.git -b branch-1.5
$ cd ./spark/
$ build/mvn -DskipTests clean package
```

Comment: It seems like a memory leak to me, i'll try to see if there is a associated JIRA to it!

Comment: Ok [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11126) it is. It should be resolved in 1.5.2 and 1.6.0

Answer (score 1):

It is a memory leak in Spark 1.5.1.

You can find the associated JIRA below :

- [SPARK-11192 - Spark sql seems to leak org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ui.SQLTaskMetrics objects over time](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11192)
- [SPARK-11126 - A memory leak in SQLListener._stageIdToStageMetrics](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11126)

The issue seems to be resolved in 1.5.2 and 1.6.0